# How to do type safe, thread safe boundaries with Akka?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

What is the accepted practice to implement module boundaries between groups of actors within akka typed?

## TL/DR

Here's a [working repo](https://github.com/joostpapendorp/akka-decoupling-example) of the example below.
How do I implement a single actor recieving messages (pre-)defined in two different protocols, analogous to implementing two different interfaces in OO.

## Example

With boundary, I mean the classical OO-interface boundary: exposing only the operations relevant to the other module.

For example: consider Alice, Bob and Charlie. Alice likes to talk to Bob and Charlie often wonders how Bob is doing. Charlie does not know about Alice (and shouldn't) and vice versa. Between each pair exists an protocol of which messages they can recieve of one another:

```
trait Protocol[ From, To ]

object Alice
{
    sealed trait BobToAlice extends Protocol[ Bob, Alice ]
    case object ApologizeToAlice extends BobToAlice
    case object LaughAtAlice extends BobToAlice
}

object Bob
{
    sealed trait AliceToBob extends Protocol[ Alice, Bob ]
    case object SingToBob extends AliceToBob
    case object ScoldBob extends AliceToBob

    sealed trait CharlieToBob extends Protocol[ Charlie, Bob ]
    case object HowYouDoinBob extends CharlieToBob
}

object Charlie
{
    sealed trait BobToCharlie extends Protocol[ Bob, Charlie ]
    case object CryToCharlie extends BobToCharlie
    case object LaughToCharlie extends BobToCharlie
}
```

The boundary here being the two faces of Bob: talking to Alice and talking to Charlie are two different protocols. Each can now talk to Bob without them needing to know about the other. Alice, for example, likes to sing, but not to be laughed at while she does:

```
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors.same
import akka.actor.typed.{ ActorRef, Behavior }

class Alice( bob: ActorRef[ Protocol[ Alice, Bob ] ] )
{
    import Alice._
    import nl.papendorp.solipsism.protocol.Bob.{ ScoldBob, SingToBob }

    val talkToBob: Behavior[ BobToAlice ] = Behaviors.receiveMessage
    {
        case LaughAtAlice =>
            bob ! ScoldBob
            same

        case ApologizeToAlice =>
            bob ! SingToBob
            same
    }
}
```

Charlie, on the other hand, is only concerned with how Bob is feeling at the moment:

```
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors.{ receiveMessage, same }
import akka.actor.typed.{ ActorRef, Behavior }

class Charlie(bob: ActorRef[Protocol[Charlie,Bob]])
{
    import Charlie._
    import nl.papendorp.solipsism.protocol.Bob.HowYouDoinBob
    
    val concerned: Behavior[BobToCharlie] = receiveMessage
    {
        case CryToCharlie =>
            bob ! HowYouDoinBob
            same

        case LaughToCharlie =>
            bob ! HowYouDoinBob
            same
    }
}
```

However, Alices effect on Bobs mood influences how Bob talks to Charlie. For that, we need to unify the two protocols via `BobsPersonalLife` to be able to represent them within a single actor:

```
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors._
import akka.actor.typed.{ ActorRef, Behavior }
import Alice.BobToAlice
import Charlie.BobToCharlie

object Bob
{
    private[ Bob ] sealed trait BobsPersonalLife

    sealed trait AliceToBob extends Protocol[Alice, Bob] with BobsPersonalLife
    case object SingToBob extends AliceToBob
    case object ScoldBob extends AliceToBob

    sealed trait CharlieToBob extends Protocol[Charlie, Bob] with BobsPersonalLife
    case object HowYouDoinBob extends CharlieToBob
}

class Bob( alice: ActorRef[BobToAlice], charlie: ActorRef[BobToCharlie] )
{
    import Alice._
    import Bob._
    import Charlie._
    
    private val happy: Behavior[ BobsPersonalLife ] = receiveMessage
    {
        case HowYouDoinBob =>
            charlie ! LaughToCharlie
            same

        case ScoldBob =>
            alice ! ApologizeToAlice
            sad

        case SingToBob =>
            alice ! LaughAtAlice
            same
    }

    val sad: Behavior[ BobsPersonalLife ] = receiveMessage
    {
        case HowYouDoinBob =>
            charlie ! CryToCharlie
            same

        case ScoldBob =>
            alice ! ApologizeToAlice
            same

        case SingToBob  =>
            alice ! LaughAtAlice
            happy
    }
}
```

So far, so good. We can instantiate Alice and Charlie using `ActorRef.narrow[ _X_ToBob ]`. But what about Bob? Or rather, Bobs alter-egos? If we want to replace Bob with Boris who doesn't complain to Charlie but to Doris, using a `DorisToBob extends Protocol[ Doris, Bob ]`, we can no longer recieve messages from Alice, since there's no shared supertrait of `AliceToBob` and `DorisToBob`. Suddenly, `BobsPersonalLife` is a lock-in for every Bob Alice can talk to.

What would be the way to be able to replace Bob with a Boris? If we would use `ActorRef.unsafeUpcast` we lose type safety. If we use two actors on a shared state, we lose thread safety. Wrapping _X_ToBob (e.g. `Either[ AliceToBob, CharlieToBob ]` or Dotty's shorthand union type) doesn't work either, since the wrapper just takes over the role of `BobsPersonalLife`. when we just let `DorisToBob` inherit from `BobsPersonalLife`, we end up with a union of all possible partners of all Bobs alter-ego's unable to remove any of them, ever.

## Question

How can we achieve true type-safe decoupling between Alice and Charlie within Bob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this verges on being an X:Y question ("how do I do interface boundaries in Akka" vs. "how do I accomplish the goal of interface boundaries in Akka").

```
object Protocol {
  sealed trait Message

  sealed trait LaughReply extends Message
  sealed trait MoodReply extends Message
  case class Apology(from: ActorRef[Singing]) extends Message
  case class Singing(from: ActorRef[Laughing]) extends Message

  case class Laughing(from: ActorRef[LaughReply]) extends Message with MoodReply
  case class HowYouDoin(replyTo: ActorRef[MoodReply]) extends Message with LaughReply
  case class Scolding(from: ActorRef[Apology]) extends Message with LaughReply
  case class Crying(from: ActorRef[HowYouDoin]) extends Message with MoodReply
}

object Alice {
  val talkToBob: Behavior[Message] = Behaviors.receive { (context, msg) =>
    msg match {
      case Apology(from) =>
        from ! Singing(context.self)
        Behaviors.same
      case Laughing(from) =>
        from ! Scolding(context.self)
        Behaviors.same
      case _ =>  // Every other message is ignored by Alice
        Behaviors.same
    }
  }
}

object Charlie {
  val concerned: Behavior[Message] = Behaviors.receive { (context, msg) =>
    msg match {
      case Crying(from) =>
        from ! HowYouDoin(context.self)
        Behaviors.same
      case Laughing(from) =>
        from ! HowYouDoin(context.self)
        Behaviors.same
      case _ =>
        Behaviors.same
    }
  }
}

object Bob {
  val happy: Behavior[Message] = Behaviors.receive { (context, msg) =>
    msg match {
      case HowYouDoin(replyTo) =>
        replyTo ! Laughing(context.self)
        Behaviors.same
      case Scolding(from) =>
        from ! Apology(context.self)
        sad
      case Singing(from) =>
        from ! Laughing(context.self)
        Behaviors.same
      case _ =>
        Behaviors.same
    }
  }
  
  val sad: Behavior[Message] = Behaviors.receive { (context, msg) =>
    msg match {
      case HowYouDoin(replyTo) =>
        replyTo ! Crying(context.self)
        Behaviors.same
      case Scolding(from) =>
        from ! Apology(context.self)
        Behaviors.same
      case Singing(from) =>
        from ! Laughing(context.self)
        Behaviors.same
      case _ =>
        Behaviors.same
    }
  }
}
```

The trick is basically protocol decomposition via mixins and encoding the state of the protocol (which messages are accepted) in the messages.  As long as no one holds a reference to an `ActorRef[Message]` (`ActorRef` is contravariant, so an `ActorRef[LaughReply]` is not an `ActorRef[Message]`), there's no way to send a message which the target hasn't committed to accepting.  Note that keeping an `ActorRef` in an actor's state actively works against this: if you're going to keep another `ActorRef` in the state of your actor, that's a pretty strong sign IMO that you're not at all interested in decoupling them.

An alternative, rather than the overarching protocol, is to have protocols for each of Alice/Bob/Charlie/etc. with the commands and replies defined only in the context of that actor and using, e.g., the typed ask pattern to adapt the reply protocol of the target actor to the command protocol of the requesting actor.